# want to store large amount of data in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on the app in which large amount of data (e.g 30K dictionary in array) is received through web service.I am using JSON kit for parsing this large amount of data.
I am recieving this data in chunk of 10k every time.

So, what is the best way to store this large amount of data plist file or SQLite database??

Comment: Do you mean 30,000 entries or 30,000 bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a sqlite database. This allows you to quickly read values without the need to store the whole list in memory. It's easy to add and remove entries. Lookup will be fast if your table has the proper index(es).

A plist would require the whole list to be in memory. 30k entries would easily fit in memory if each entry is just a word. But if it's more data or you never need the whole list at once, you really don't want all of that in memory.

CoreData is probably serious overkill for just a list.

Comment: Whole data is in dictionary format in an Array and i am currently using plist file to store this data. This will affect on the memory of the iPad. So SQlite is better right??

Comment: Right. The whole plist is in memory at once and it is hard to search. A database isn't in memory and it is easy to perform searches.

Comment: Thanks. What about core data??

Comment: As I said, overkill for this use. Read up about CoreData in the docs. You'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is best option to store large amount of data in iOS programming, because when you use any other method for storing purpose, it will require memory at run-time along with processing power to retrieve desired piece of data. using SQLite, you can run a query that will return specific piece if data easily.
hopefully this will help you.